# Javascript code runs when outside the function but doesn't run when inside the function

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="color" >This paragraph may change color </p>
<input type="button" value="Change color" onclick="change()">

<script type="text/javascript">
var colors=["red","blue","green","yellow"];
var changed=0;

function change(){
        document.getElementById('color').style.color=colors[changed]; 
        changed=changed+1;
    }
</script>
```

This changes color on click but when two variables are kept inside the function,it doesn't work...Can Someone explain to me why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function change(){

    var colors=["red","blue","green","yellow"];
    var changed=0;
    console.log(changed);
    document.getElementById('color').style.color=colors[changed]; 
    changed=changed+1;
    console.log(changed);
}
```

```html
<p id="color" >This paragraph may change color </p>
<input type="button" value="Change color" onclick="change()">
```

It changes color but only once, that is because `changed` is initialized to 0 everytime you call `change()`, so everytime it becomes `document.getElementById('color').style.color=colors[0]` and that changes color to red but doesn't change again..

Comment: So why doesn't it execute *changed=changed+1;* statement when inside the function?

Comment: it does execute `changed=changed+1` but when you call `change()` again `changed` becomes 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

If you put these variables into the function, they are created when the function starts and deleted after it finishes. So, "changed" will always be 0.